Why is there a copy here of an integer?
I found a thread on the Rust Subreddit with the following question:

Why doesnt x get moved here? Should the last println even compile?
fn main() {
    let x = 5;
    {
        let x = x * 2;
        println!("inner scope {x}");
    }
    println!("outer scope {x}");
}

-- Output -- inner scope 10 outer scope 5

And all the responses in that subreddit were that x gets "copied" because x is i32 and i32 implements the copy trait. However I don't see at all where a move OR a copy should happen.
let x = 5;
{
    let x = x * 2; // WHY IS THERE A COPY HERE?
    println!("inner scope {x}");
}

I don't get why there's a copy. It's not like C++ where (x * 2) is an expression that just reads 'outer' x and multiplies it by two and initialises the 'inner' x with that value. Does it do a move or something when it reads the outer 'x'?

Its because xis moved into the Mul function: https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/ops/arith.rs.html#349

The relevant, and accurate, answer from Reddit was:

x is an integer, integers implement Copy. Copy types are not moved.

It helps to understand how Rust handles the multiplication operator, *. As implied by operator documentation, it's an alias for the std::ops::Mul::mul function:
use std::ops::Mul;

let x = 5;

// Old line:
// let x = x * 2;

// New line with identical semantics:
let x = x.mul(2);

Looking at how the Mul trait is defined, we can infer that its first argument must be an owned i32, since it needs to match the left operand x's type.
pub trait Mul<Rhs = Self> {
    type Output;
    fn mul(self, rhs: Rhs) -> Self::Output;
}

To to derive an owned i32 to call mul with from an owned i32 in x, a copy needs to be made. If x was not a Copy type, it would be moved instead. Either way, the copying/moving is implicit/invisible, so it's understandable you didn't see it. The result of multiplication is assigned to x in the inner scope, which shadows x in the outer scope for the purpose of printing in the inner scope. Since the outer x could be copied, and so was not moved, it remains valid to print in the outer scope.
I also want to point out that multiplication in Rust can be done without moving or Copying. You just have to implement std::ops::Mul on the reference to your type, and use & for each operand of * that isn't already a reference.
struct MulNotCopy(String);

impl std::ops::Mul for &MulNotCopy {
    type Output = MulNotCopy;
    fn mul(self, other: Self) -> MulNotCopy {
        MulNotCopy(format!("{} * {}", self.0, other.0))
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let x = MulNotCopy("5".to_owned());
    let x = &x * &MulNotCopy("2".to_owned());
}


I see. Can I assume that +, -, /, well, basically any operator is basically a function call conceptually?

Good question; the same applies to all other arithmetic operators, all bitwise operators, all comparison operators, and some memory-related operators (* -> Deref::deref / DerefMut::deref_mut). There are some operators that are not functions, such as & (borrow). You can find a full list of operators here, and the right-most column shows you any associated trait (function).

@Zebrafish it is a bit similar to the operator keyword in C++. The usual notation with +, -, / ... is a  convenient shortcut for a function call.
